# Virtuemart joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Does anyone know how to link a product with its picture in VirtueMart in Joomla?

I've tried :

> $query = "SELECT  a.*, c.*".
>                 " FROM #__virtuemart_products_pl_pl as a".
>                     " LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_medias as c ON c.virtuemart_media_id = a.virtuemart_product_id" ;

But its not good, pictures and products don't match.

I don't see any connection between them.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
select p.virtuemart_product_id,m.virtuemart_media_id,md.file_url 
  from #__virtuemart_products as p,
       #__virtuemart_product_medias as m,
       #__virtuemart_medias  as md
 WHERE p.virtuemart_product_id = m.virtuemart_product_id
   AND m.virtuemart_media_id = md.virtuemart_media_id
```